# Flutter commands not working in cmd, powershell or gitbash

Tags: flutter, powershell, dart

I format my laptop and installed windows, and I wanted to reinstall flutter on my new OS. I downloaded the installation bundle and extracted them as stated in the official documentation. But, when I try to run any command a cmd pops up with some messages and suddenly vanishes, and there is nothing happening. I have attached the screenshots of my PowerShell version and user env variables below.

[image: image of powershel]

[image: image on env]

Comment: Did you restart the device and what do you get after using `flutter`

Comment: Thanks for including info about PATH straight away, removes a debugging step. "try to run any command a cmd pops up with some messages and suddenly vanishes": could you tell us the messages (maybe use a screen recorder and slow-mo if you can't see them?)

Comment: Thank you for the response @JaffaKetchup
, I was able to gab a screenshot of the mesage thats pop up, ```https://i.ibb.co/KyyjMM9/img3.png```

Comment: Thank you for the response Yeasin Sheikh, I have attached a screenshot of the the popup cmd , for every command the same popup shows and suddenly vanishes,

Comment: Not sure what the issue could be. The text looks correct, and shows DART is working. Have you tried the `flutter` command as well? Does the popup immediately disappear or after you type something or after a while?

Comment: same goes with `flutter` command as well, the cmd pop up when I type a command and press enter, then it immediately disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Formatting the computer makes things work again, There was some sort of malware that makes all my .exe files and batch files corrupt and it runs some processes, always try following the guidelines in the official documentation, and always double-check the processes in your system as well.